CKeditor balloon toolbar custom id
Hello everyone I try to add custom id in the ckeditor5 balloon toolbar, I have to many instances and I want to know which balloon user have clicked I use ckeditor5 inline in angular, I add id attribute but it doesn't applied in the balloon toolbar data attribute will also help thanks
I try to add id in the ckeditor5 component in angular but it didn't applied in the balloon toolbar
